# Spring edition? (5) - cryptic crossword clue explanation

Tags: cryptic-clues, crosswords

I'm just solving a cryptic crossword and had the clue...

> Spring edition? (5)

With the letters...

> _ S _ _ _

I guessed it was `ISSUE` and upon checking on google found I was right. But I don't understand the reason why I was right.

I can connect the "edition" part of the clue. I was thinking of "version" and other similar words. But I can't work out what "Spring edition?" adds to the clue?

Comment: Think that is a cryptic definition.

Comment: It's relying on the "originate from" or "arise from" definition of the word "spring". As in "Athena sprang from Zeus' forehead". Thus, it's a synonym for issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a double definition. For the first half, consider "spring from" and "issue from". For the second, consider an issue of a magazine. (The first half is the bit you didn't already have.)

Comment: I feel bad because Hugh's comment was actually about 10 seconds before my answer (totally independent, of course) -- but, well, Hugh should have made it an answer and not a comment :-).

Comment: I'm not sure you've got the usage quite right, though. In the first half, "spring" and "issue" are both *intransitive* verbs: as Hugh says, consider Athena springing from Zeus's forehead or water springing from the ground.

Comment: (And now I've written the word "spring" too many times in rapid succession and it's no longer looking like a real word. I hate it when that happens.)

Comment: Yeah, my description was not very good. I do understand it though. Thanks :D and that's called "semantic satiation" FYI :P

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan No problem. I would certainly have made it an answer if I had wanted credit. I've been purely an asker for quite a while now.